# Adding elements dynamically in HTML for each section with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

Adding a task (input + label) dynamically for each specific section/div when I enter the name and press the button "Add".

I've tried to make an event for each button and then add a task for the specific div of that specific section but I couldn't implement it. Is there any solution for this?

This is the HTML:

```
<section id="1" class="1">
    <div id="div1" class="add-input-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
        <label for="checkbox-1">Test</label>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-div-1" class="btn-div-1">
        <input type="text" id="input-text-1">
        <button id="btn-1" class="btn-add">Add</button>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="2" class="2">
    <div id="div2" class="add-input-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
        <label for="checkbox-2">Test</label>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-div-2" class="btn-div-2">
        <input type="text" id="input-text-2">
        <button id="btn-2" class="btn-add">Add</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

and this is the Javascript:

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add');
const div = document.querySelectorAll('.add-input-label');

btn.forEach((btn) => {
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.forEach((div) => {
        let label = document.createElement('label');
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        div.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(label);
        label.innerText = 'hey';
        input.type = 'checkbox';
    });
});
```

});

Notice that when you click the button, it adds on both sections. If I clicked on the first section button, I wanted to change just the first section.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the attempt(s) you made so far.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few changes you need to made on your code to achieve what you wanted.

1. Make use of `forEach` [index syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax). With the index `i` in `btn.forEach((btn,i)`, you can use it to differentiate on the button's index.
2. You dont need another `forEach` on the `div`. In button click listener, just use the button index you got earlier and perform the same indexing on the `div` to make sure that `appendChild` is appending on the correct `div`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add');
const div = document.querySelectorAll('.add-input-label');
btn.forEach((btn,i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let label = document.createElement('label');
      let input = document.createElement('input');
      div[i].appendChild(input);
      div[i].appendChild(label);
      label.innerText = 'hey';
      input.type = 'checkbox';
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="1" class="1">
    <div id="div1" class="add-input-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
        <label for="checkbox-1">Test</label>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-div-1" class="btn-div-1">
        <input type="text" id="input-text-1">
        <button id="btn-1" class="btn-add">Add</button>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="2" class="2">
    <div id="div2" class="add-input-label">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
        <label for="checkbox-2">Test</label>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-div-2" class="btn-div-2">
        <input type="text" id="input-text-2">
        <button id="btn-2" class="btn-add">Add</button>
    </div>
</section>
```